# How to get px height of the element with CSS height auto MooTools?

Tags: mootools

Is there any way to get actual element height ?
 getSize().y
returns 0 since element has property height auto?
even if you declare image inline property to auto you get 0 back?

Thank you!

Comment: never mind , had to do load instead domready , must wait for elements to load first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you had a different issue, but to make this future-relevant, the mechanisms in MooTools for this are (for an element with the id `x`:

```
$('x').getSize().y
```

or

```
$('x').getCoordinates().height
```

Either of which will return an integer (no units) of the pixel height. So a 100 pixel tall element would return `100` for either of these.

You could also use the non-MooTools specific `getComputedStyle` method:

```
$('x').getComputedStyle('height')
```

Which returns the element height with the unit. So a 100 pixel tall element would return `100px`.